# Session down trying to connect sftp using jsch package in java

Tags: java

Please provide feasibility of solution above problem trying to connect server to server not able to connect getting session down

Tried with Google solution didn't work looking for better solution for jsch utilities

Kindly help me to resolve issue

Comment: You do understand that it's probably impossible for anyone to guess what your issue might be when you don't include any details at all.